# Should I configure multiple publish targets to publish to multiple environments?

Tags: best-practices, publishing

We have several environments:

1. Our production / live site.
2. Our staging / QA site.
3. Our development site.
4. Local developer's machines.

I know sitecore supports several ways to publish, including packages and 3rd party tools like TDS, but is there any reason I couldn't (or shouldn't) just configure a publish target for each environment?  When I publish from our development site to our QA site, for instance, I could just publish and check the QA target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your overall question is that you should ***not publish across across environments.*** Can you? Sitecore is so flexible that you can create publishing targets to all kinds of Sitecore databases without Sitecore complaining too much.

However, there are a lot of gotchas that fall into play here.

1. Publishing causes events to fire. You may not want events to fire across environments.
2. Connection Strings become incredibly messy.
3. The differences between environments can become muddled.
4. Caching and Indexing confusion (Thanks Derek!)
5. Event Queue cluttering and confusion

### Environments

Let's talk about environments. When I refer to an **environment** I mean:

> All of the instances of Sitecore that make up the collection of code
>   bases and config files that are treated with the same level of
>   consideration and protection.

For example:
The **Production** environment may include:

- 2 CM servers
- 3 CD servers
- 1 processing server
- 1 reporting server.

All of these servers have share distinct copies of databases (master, web, core, etc). In addition, your backup measures are vast, the servers are protected and security is very important.

But your **QA** environment may only have 1 server of each above. And if in the middle of an upgrade may be a different version level. And it might not be backed up as much.

Same with your **Dev** Environment. Rate of change is constant.

### Summary

The **Best Practice** is that you ***don't*** want to cross streams between these environments using publishing mechanisms.

*Instead*, proper file and item deployment methodologies should be employed such as:

- TDS or Unicorn item serialization synchronization
- Configuration file transformation based on environment and role
- Database backups and restores to lower environments between projects to keep them fresh.

Comment: +1 for the great answer. I would also add caching to the list of gotchas. If you publish from DEV/master to QA/master, the changes won't be visible until data caches are cleared.

Comment: Thanks, Pete.  I posted a follow up question: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/when-should-i-define-a-new-publish-target